# how can i click the button if the xpath has changed somehow

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

here is the code:
Gen_enemy = driver.find_element_by_class_name('kt-callout__action')

```
for i in range(5):

    time.sleep(y)

    Gen_enemy.click()

    time.sleep(y)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[3]/button[1]').click()

    time.sleep(b)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[3]/button[1]').click()

    time.sleep(y)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="attackButton"]').click()
    inBattle = True

    while inBattle == True:

        time.sleep(Q)

        try:
            time.sleep(a)

            Rewards = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[3]/button[1]')
            Rewards.click()

            time.sleep(a)

            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#success-killed > div.alert-text > div > a').click()

            time.sleep(b)

            inBattle = False


        except :
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="attackButton"]').click()
```

The Error:
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem once and the solution for me was to declare the object again, because the class was updated.

Here is the solution I've used.

```
campo_de_comentário = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh")
campo_de_comentário.click()
campo_de_comentário = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh.focus-visible")
campo_de_comentário.send_keys(text)
```

My code was trying to find the commentary field by class name of an instagram picture. Once I clicked it, the class name changed. So, when I tried to send the keys I got the same error as you.

Later on using selenium, I found out that the best way to search an element is by XPATH. It never fails for me.

Comment: Thank you very much a fast and simple answer great help(ive been stuck on this problem for like 2 days now)